# Is is possible to use a custom resolver instead of the hubname attribute to resolve signalr hubs?

Tags: signalr, ioc-container, signalr-hub

All of my SignalRHubs have their own service interface, this is used on the client side for type safe calling; ie no more referring to methods by string.

Anyways with this setup I have had to add a HubName attribute to all my hubs with the Interface name. Is it even possible to have the hubs resolved by these interfaces.

I did try replacing the resolver both in GlobalHost and in the HubConfiguration object with a Ninject resolver but it didn't seem to ever call the resolved for the hubs themselves.

Here is an example of a hub:

```
[HubName("IFoobarService")]
public class FoobarHub : Hub, IFoobarService
{
    public void Baz(BazDto dto)
    {
        Clients.Others.Baz(dto);
    }
}
```

}

Here is the code I used to try to bind my hubs with Ninject
     kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly()
                .SelectAllClasses()
                .InheritedFrom()
                .BindAllInterfaces());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using the HubName attribute is your best bet.

You *could* provide your own IHubDescriptorProvider and register it with SignalR's DependencyResolver, but I wouldn't recommend it.

You can take a look at the default IHubDescriptorProvider implemenation here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/2.0.2/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/Lookup/ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider.cs#L56

Notice the following line of code:

```cs
var hubDescriptors = types
    .Select(type => new HubDescriptor
                    {
                        NameSpecified = (type.GetHubAttributeName() != null),
                        Name = type.GetHubName(),
                        HubType = type
                    });
```

Type.GetHubName() is implemented as an extension method here:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/2.0.2/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/Extensions/HubTypeExtensions.cs#L9

You *could* replace the ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider with your own IHubDescriptorProvider implementation that calls into your own GetHubName method, but I think that would be overkill.

Once again, I think using the HubName attribute is your best bet.

Comment: Would there be any downside to providing my own HubDescriptorProvider?

Comment: If you were to upgrade SignalR after the implementation of the ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider changes, your app wouldn't be taking advantage of the fixes/improvements to ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider unless you manually patch your custom IHubDescriptorProvider.

Comment: Ok maybe I will try the same approach that the Ninject example had used and inherit the class so that it can fallback to the default usage. Thanks for your help.